# Looking for a US state file for geofences with as few geofences per state as possible (so group islands with mainland)

Tags: polygon, gis-principle, convex-hull, concave-hull, geofencing

**UPDATED TO MUCH MORE DETAILED QUESTION**

I'm building a set of geofences to be installed on a GPS unit to track vehicles as they cross state lines.  The list of geofences are simple latitude/longitude pairs, but each geofence needs to be a single polygon.  The problem I'm having is that all datasets I find include a polygon for EVERY body of land (so every island off of Maine gets its own geofence).

What I'm looking for is something more like this: [image]

Notice how Massachusetts is a single geofence, as is Rhode Island and Connecticut.  **Including water in the geofence is fine.**

I know this isn't possible for some states due to [the Kentucky Bend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kentucky_Bend), but I don't know if there are other exclaves (or enclaves) in the United States.  In the case of Kentucky, I could simply have a Kentucky_Geofence_1 and Kentucky_Geofence_2, whereas I'd only need 1 for each of the three green states illustrated above.

As long as there's a way to export the data from a given format to JSON, XML, CSV, etc, I don't care what the file format is.  I'm also not opposed to buying it, if it's already out there.

Again, because water doesn't matter, Alaska could look something like this:[image]

And Michigan could look something like this (but ideally with better resolution on the borders):
[image]

(These images come from a custom Google Map I've been tweaking manually by dragging-and-dropping pins to manually create these, but it's going to take a LONG time to do them all, and it seems like this must have been done somewhere else already....)

Comment: @PolyGeo Why was "geofencing" not a correct tag for this?

Comment: What you are describing are multi-part polygons. What GIS software are you using, or is it only Google Maps that you are trying to do this with?

Comment: I'm using Google Maps / Earth, but open to using any to be honest.  I'm new to GIS, so if I'm using the wrong language I didn't know.  I thought Geofences were polygons (one or many) which signify a geographical area.  (I *am* trying to export these polygons for software triggering purposes...)

Comment: Actually I think you are looking for a concave hull around your multi-part polygon. You make no mention of geofencing in your question although I would imagine that a concave hull could be used by a geofencing application.

Comment: @PolyGeo He seems to be after State legal (including maritime) boundaries as per https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240261/what-are-the-state-border-outlines-called-which-treat-every-state-as-a-single-en

Comment: Or are you just looking for a dataset with the US states as concave hulls?  I would imagine that exists so researching/asking at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange may be an alternative to making them.

Comment: @Midavalo Could be - I thought they might go a lot further out from the coast but I've never looked into them for any country.

Comment: I am pushing back on the people who gave me these requirements, because they haven't defined them nearly well enough to address all of these good points you have (both) brought up, thank you.  I will also try Open Data and studying a bit more GIS terminology to see if I can better phrase my question(s) than I have been... apologies for my "newbie"ness...

Comment: and to get you going while on excursion into GIS: check out naturalearthdata.com. that's one rather famous Open Data provider, and: they might have what you need (I am not 100% sure with only guessing your data needs and also without checking, but I think I remember seeing administrative polygons with marine borders there)

Comment: After conferring with them, what I'm looking for is the minimum number of polygons PER STATE which covers that whole state's landmass (these polygons can include as much water as needed).  So in my original image above, Massachusetts could be done with a single polygon.  Ditto for Rhode Island, or even Alaska.  Unless there are other Exclaves like the Kentucky Bend (so Kentucky requires AT LEAST 2 polygons/geofences), it may never require more than one per state.

Should I amend this question, or post it as a new one?  Or is this a pretty simple request to find/generate?

Comment: I have updated the question accordingly, with more details.